# change of random variable in calculating expectations: $\mathbb{E}_x [f(X)] = \mathbb{E}_z [f(g(Z))] $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be some function $g$ of a random variable $Z$, such that $X=g(Z)$.
Does the following hold in general? If so, how should I give a formal proof?
$$\mathbb{E}_x [f(X)] = \mathbb{E}_z [f(g(Z))] $$

For example, in showing the linearity of expectation, it's common to let $X=aZ+b$, then write $\mathbb{E}_x[X]=\mathbb{E}_z[aZ+b] = \int_{dz}(az+b) f(z) = a \mathbb{E}_z[Z] + b $, where I've always treated expectation $\mathbb{E}$ as an operator that averages w.r.t. the distribution of whatever random quantity in the argument.

Comment: The answer is yes but for the proof you have to use measure theory.

Comment: Notation troubles, which might signal understanding troubles: please replace $E_x$ and $E_z$ by $E$; and the step $E(aZ+b)=\int_{dz}as+b$ is absurd.

Comment: @Did: well I forgot to include the density function $f(z)$ (assuming $Z$ is continuous). The subscript notation is somewhat standard in applied work as a way of clarifying which random variable is to be averaged over like in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226136) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00670.pdf).

Comment: I'd appreciate it if anyone would bother to actually answer the question if it's so apparently trivial.

Comment: Yeah the subscript is an unfortunate remnant of inadequate curricula, completely illogical mathematically speaking, and with catastrophical consequences pedagogically speaking. To be eliminated as soon as possible.

Comment: Re the question itself, where is the problem with the identity $$\int_\mathbb R(az+b)f(z)dz=a\int_\mathbb Rzf(z)dz+b\ ?$$

Comment: I think you have the gist of the right idea about this "change of variable", but realize that the tricky part is managing the distribution of the new variable in a way that "subsumes" the distribution of the original variable correctly.  Then the computation of expected value will be done properly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've finally learned enough measure theoretic probability to answer this question :)

It really just comes down to the formal definition of the expectation of a random variable, and the transformation ("change of measure") theorem.

The transformation theorem (see e.g., Schilling text theorem 15.1) basically says that given an "original" measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and a measurable map $T: \Omega \to \Gamma$,  integrating a measurable function $u: \Gamma \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ w.r.t. the image measure $T(\mu) = \mu \circ T^{-1}$ is the same as integrating the composite function $u \circ T$ w.r.t. the "original" measure $\mu$,
i.e.,
$$\int_{\Gamma} u \text{ d} T(\mu) = \int_\mathcal{\Omega} u \circ T \text{ d} \mu(z) $$

So to justify the identity "$\mathbb{E}_x[X]=\mathbb{E}_z[aZ+b]$ if $X = g(Z) = aZ + b$" that I previously asked about, we just need to apply the above theorem to change the measure with respect to which we integrate from the probability law $\mathbb{P}$ of the underlying sample space $\Omega$, to the distribution $\mathbb{P}_Z:=Z(\mathbb{P})$ of $Z$, and finally to the distribution $\mathbb{P}_X:= g(Z(\mathbb{P})) = g(\mathbb{P}_Z)$ of $X:=g \circ Z$:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[g \circ Z]:= \int_\mathcal{\Omega} g \circ Z \text{ d} \mathbb{P} = \int g \text{ d} \mathbb{P}_Z =  \int x \text{ d} \mathbb{P}_X(x) $$

(the $u$ function in the last change of measure step is just the identity function, $u(x) = x$, and we consider $g: z \to x$ to be a random variable with $ \mathbb{E}[g]: = \int g \text{ d} \mathbb{P}_Z$).

In my example, $g(z) = az + b$, and suppose $\mathbb{P}_Z$ has density $f_Z$, $\mathbb{P}_X$ has density $f_X$, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X] := \int g \circ Z \text{ d} \mathbb{P} = \int (az + b )\text{ d} \mathbb{P}_Z (z) = \int (az + b) f_Z(z) \text{ d}z  = \int x f_X(x) \text{ d} x $$
as desired.

Comment: Schilling is such a great textbook since it gives so many nice basic problems so you can comfortable with some really ugly notation conventions.